# EJS & Mongoose: How to capture & show a single category from schema model array?

Tags: ejs, mongoose-schema

I tried to find it, but I didn't get with the correct answer.
I'm using Mongoose, node.js and EJS for views.

I have been able to catch & show all the schema categories of rooms model. Except the categories inside the Array "nights".

Here is one example of the seed model

```js
 const rooms = [
    {
    category: "Estándar",
    type: "Doble",
    view: "Interior",
    capacity: 2,
    size: 20,
    typeOfBed: "Dos camas individuales",
    description: "Encantadora habitación decorada con detalles rústicos",
    price: 100,
    photo: "http://maxpixel.freegreatpicture.com/static/photo/2x/New-Hotel-Guest-Room-1330846.jpg",
    nights: [
      { date: new Date('2017-09-12'), booked: true }, 
      { date: new Date('2017-09-13'), booked: false }
    ]
    },
```

Here is how I catch it with EJS

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Imagen</th>
            <th>Tipo </th>
            <th>Categoría</th>
            <th>Vista</th>
            <th>Máximo de personas</th>
            <th>Tamaño en m2</th>
            <th>Tipo de cama</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Descripción</th>
            <th> Noches </th>
            <th> Reservado </th>
            <th> Fecha de llegada </th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <% rooms.forEach((roomData) => { %>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td scope="row"><img class="roomPic" src="<%= roomData.photo %>" alt="roompicture"></td>
            <td><%= roomData.type %> </td>
            <td><%= roomData.category %></td>
            <td><%= roomData.view %> </td>
            <td><%= roomData.capacity %></td>
            <td><%= roomData.size %></td>
            <td><%= roomData.typeOfBed %></td>
            <td><%= roomData.price %></td>
            <td><%= roomData.description %></td>
            <td><%= roomData.nights %> </td>
            <td><%= roomData.nights.booked %> </td>
            <td><%= roomData.date %> </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/rooms/<%= roomData._id %>/edit"> 
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"> Editar </button> 
                </a>
            </td>
            <th>   
                <form action="/rooms/<%= roomData._id %>/delete" method="POST">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"> Borrar </button>
                </form>
            </th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
            <%  }); %>
    </table>
```

And the result is this one, as you can see is not showing "date" & "booked"

[ScreenShot of the rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YOPY.png)

¿how I can show individually the nights array values "booked" & "date"??

Thanks for your HelP!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't query like this `<%= roomData.nights.booked %>`
One solution i can think of is pre-compute the booked and non booked lists and use those lists. Something like below.

Pre compute the lists:

```
<%
var bookedRooms = [];
var nonBookedRooms = [];

rooms.nights.forEach(function(entry){
  if(entry.booked == true){
    bookedRooms.push(entry);
  }else{
    nonBookedRooms.push(entry);
  }
});
%>
```

Use the lists in your columns

```
<td><%= bookedRooms %> </td>
```

Comment: Thank you very much men, I will try it!